# ManagementEventWatcher leading to unit test exiting with System.AppDomainUnloadedException

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm instantiating a ManagementEventWatcher object in some code which I'm trying to unit test. The test exits with a warning:

> "System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded
>   AppDomain. This can happen if the test(s) started a thread but did not
>   stop it. Make sure that all the threads started by the test(s) are
>   stopped before completion."

Can anyone tell me how to clear the error or what I'm doing wrong?

```
using System.Management;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

public class EventWatcherPolling
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunEventWatcher();
        return 0;
    }

    public static void RunEventWatcher()
    {
        ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher();
        watcher.Stop();
        watcher.Dispose();
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        EventWatcherPolling.RunEventWatcher();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's generally not much you can do about that error: it looks like the garbage collector hasn't got round to collecting the watcher,  so you could try waiting after the test has run for that.

Comment: what are you trying to test?

Comment: A class which instantiates a ManagementEventWatcher in it's constructor (not my design...). I guess dependency injection is the way forward here.